# Accidentally deleted many hidden files with "git clean -fd" and now I cannot install Ruby

Tags: ruby, git, bash, terminal, rbenv

So I really messed up on this one.....
I was working on a rails application and wanted to revert back to a previous commit. I opened a new shell and forgot to cd into my projects folder, so I ran "git reset --hard" and then "git clean -fd" in my user directory. I noticed before everything was gone, but here is what got deleted:

```
bash-3.2$ git clean -fd
Removing .CFUserTextEncoding
Removing .Trash/
Removing .Xauthority
Removing .adobe/
Removing .bash_history
Removing .bash_profile
Removing .bundle/
Removing .config/
Removing .cups/
Removing .dropbox/
Removing .fontconfig/
Removing .gem/
Removing .gitconfig
Removing .guard_history
Removing .heroku/
Removing .irb-history
Removing .irb_history
Removing .lesshst
Removing .macports/
^C
```

I was able to save my project in that shell, but I (now realized stupidly) thought restarting my computer would be best once I realized my rails and bundle commands were not working in another shell. Unfortunately I lost that working shell which I through researching realize would have helped.

What is done is done, and I am trying to fix everything, but something I cannot get right is installing ruby. I am using rbenv to install ruby but even after installing it, it won't register with in any shell:

```
-bash-3.2$ rbenv local
2.1.1
-bash-3.2$ ruby -v
-bash: ruby: command not found
```

I am a bit inexperienced when it comes to the terminal and I am freaking out. I am wondering if I should restore factory settings. My important pictures and documents are backed up but I don't use time machine.

I don't know if it is just ruby which is the problem, so far nothing else has been an issue, but I would appreciate any help solving the problem!

**EDIT**

So I realize now that the issue was deleting my bash_profile which has had all sorts of knock on effects. I really don't know how to fix or reset it....I am trying to uninstall everything and reinstall it but I am having trouble figuring out what. I tried installing ruby via mac ports, which worked, but it was not sending the message to rbenv.

Comment: Have you sourced the shell profile again after installing ruby? Try logging in and out.

Comment: Have you restored your .bash_profile and added the rbenv init code there. You could try: echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile then rbenv may work properly

Comment: I have restored the .bash_profile, but no I have not added the rbenv code. That did not seem to work, I tried installing ruby via macports, which worked, but it was dissociated from rbenv so I am trying to reinstall rbenv now i guess

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh) to install rbenv.  It has worked better for me than MacPorts did.

This older post [Modern Ruby Development (on Mac)](http://ascarter.net/2011/09/25/modern-ruby-development.html) is still very helpful.

The install for HomeBrew needs ruby, which will be a problem for you as you have lost ruby.

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`

The rbenv lines you need in your .bash_profile, according to the [rbenv install docs](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#basic-github-checkout), are,

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Do not forget to say, `source .bash_profile` after editing the profile, or open a new terminal.

If your rbenv command is no longer available, you can install it directly from git with,

```
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
```

That is assuming the `git` command still works.

With the rbenv lines restored to your .bash_profile, you might be able to install a ruby with,

```
rbenv install 2.1.1
```

(`rbenv install -l` will list available versions. Any of the lines output from there can go after `rbenv install`.)

Finally, use `rbenv global` to set the default ruby to one of the rbenv installed ones.

```
rbenv global 2.1.1
```

You can view the current global ruby set for rbenv with,

```
rbenv global
```

As you know,

```
ruby -v
```

will get the version of the ruby that runs by default.  You might not know that,

```
which ruby
```

will tell you where the shell finds that ruby command in your path.

Comment: Hey! I appreciate the help but I had already reset my computer :(, I got everything working now though, thanks!